# Output foreach loop used in Wordpress wp_customize

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm trying to dynamically output some settings from theme Customizer. I use this [custom controls](https://maddisondesigns.com/2017/05/the-wordpress-customizer-a-developers-guide-part-2/#sortablepillcheckbox), Example 3.

How can I output the settings so that the selected options appear as well as in the order in which they were placed in Customizer?

So far I've tried without success:

```
    $box = get_theme_mod( 'sample_pill_checkbox3' ) ;
 
    switch ( $box ) {

                case 'author':
                echo 'Author';
                break;

                case 'date':
                echo 'Date' ;
                break;
}
```

Basically, if Author and Date is selected and Date is placed first, so I would need to appear in the frontend, Date first then Author.

Thank you!

Comment: What you're asking is actually a generic PHP question.. and looking at the [code](https://github.com/maddisondesigns/customizer-custom-controls), you'd want to do `$list = explode( ',', $box );` then loop through the array.

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm not that good at php. What should my code look like? Can you formulate an answer please?

Comment: Try with `$list = explode( ',', $box ); foreach ( $list as $value ) { switch ( $value ) { // your code here } }` - and if it works the way you expected, then you can write your own answer (and accept it later).

Comment: @SallyCJ Brilliant! Work like charm! You can add your answer, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have in question (`switch ( $box )`) won't work because the value of the `$box` variable is in the form of `<value>,<value>,<value>,...`, i.e. *comma-separated list* of values (like the default ones [here](https://github.com/maddisondesigns/customizer-custom-controls/blob/7b8f5926645ff4240a67745ecb22f48739aabcaa/functions.php#L231) — `author,categories,comments`), so in order to get access to each value in that list, you'd want to parse the values into an array, e.g. using the native `explode()` function in PHP, just like how the theme author [did it](https://github.com/maddisondesigns/customizer-custom-controls/blob/7b8f5926645ff4240a67745ecb22f48739aabcaa/inc/custom-controls.php#L991).

Then after that, just loop through the array and run the `switch` call for each item in the array. (Note that the items are already in the same order they were placed via the Customizer)

**Working Example**

```php
$list = explode( ',', $box );

foreach ( $list as $value ) {
    switch ( $value ) {
        case 'author':
            echo 'Author';
            break;

        case 'date':
            echo 'Date';
            break;

        // ... your code.
    }
}
```

<sup>PS: Just a gentle reminder — if you need a generic PHP help like this again, you should ask on Stack Overflow.. =)</sup>